# "add more logins" in Area 51 Discussion Zone leads to 404

Tags: bug, profile-page, area-51

I noticed that the Dicsussion Zone of Area 51 got the new profile page design, and it's really awesome.

However, when going to "Settings" then "My Logins", the "add more logins" link is not really working:

> [image]

It points to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent which currently gives a 404 Page Not Found error.